# How ngModel access error property in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngmodel

I have following form in angular:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createStock(stockForm)" #stockForm="ngForm">    
    <div class="stock-name">
      <input type="text"
             placeholder="Stock Name"
             required
             name="stockName"
             #stockName="ngModel"                                   
             [(ngModel)]="stock.name">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="stockName.errors && stockName.errors.required">     
        Stock Name is Mandatory
    </div>
```

As you can, I am creating a template reference variable (stockName) and assigning ngModel to it. Later I am using that template reference variable to check errors. The above code is working fine but I am unable to understand why its working fine when there is no such property called "errors" exist in the NgModel class.

Comment: You need to switch from template driven to reactive forms to get the errors property on `FormGroup`. How to do that is beyond the scope of this forum. If you don't want to switch, just write your own validation and attach it to the `(change) ` event.

Comment: The above code is working fine. But I don't understand how could I access errors property when it does not even exist on ngmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My only question is why stockName.errors is working when there is no such errors property exist in the NgModel directive

There is an `errors` property of type [`ValidationErrors`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors) on [`NgModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#template-variable-references) as [`NgModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#template-variable-references) inherits from [`NgControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl) which inherits from [`AbstractControlDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective) and this has that property.

The [angular API documentation](https://angular.io/api) is very well written and easy to navigate around in. I frequently find myself using it when I am not sure if a type has a supported member I am needing to use.

Comment: I think I could not explain my question well. The code I posted is working fine. My only question is why stockName.errors is working when there is no such errors property exist in the NgModel directive

Comment: @Tarun - ok, that makes more sense. Thank you for clarifying your question. I updated my answer accordingly and supplied supporting documentation links.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question:
**NgModel extends NgControl** and **NgControl extends AbstractControlDirective**.
   AbstractControlDirective makes errors property available to NgModel.
When we try to access ngModel.errors, It internally access the property defined on FormControl (Created by ngmodel) as:

```
this.control.errors
```

In short ngModel.errors is a syntactic sugar.